# Wordpress advanced custom fields plugin is not giving output correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have 2 similar lines of code, the first one works OK but the second is not.

This one works ok and displays the title within the `<li></li>`

```
$output .= '<li>' . the_title() . '</li>';
```

This one returns an **empty `<li></li>`** and displays the result on top of the page

```
$output .= '<li>' . the_field('price') . '</li>';
```

the_field('price') is a custom wordpress field which i've created by using "Advanced Custom Fields" plugin. Here is the documentation of the plugin on how to output the data http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/select/

Comment: what is `the_field` ? A PHP function ? Where is it declared ? Please give more code (PHP, HTML) in order to give you a better answer

Comment: Clearly the problem is with `the_field(price)`. You'll need to edit your answer with the declaration of that function to get real help.

Comment: Well, `the_field` is a standard Wordpress function, and the question is tagged as being a Wordpress question...

Comment: Oops, sorry, not a standard Wordpress function, it appears to come from the "Advanced Custom Fields" plugin: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/the_field/

Comment: The field could be empty for the current record.

Comment: Try running `var_dump(get_field('price'));` to know exactly what it's returning (my guess is null or an empty string).

Comment: I should add that I know just the basics on PHP, but when i've tried var_dump(get_field('price')); it says  bool(false)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, perhaps its better to use [get_field()](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/get_field/) instead of [the_field()](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/the_field/).

Here is the difference:

- `get_field()` will give you the value.
- `the_field()` will print the result directly but return NULL.

Comment: Not only is it better to use `get_field`, it's the only way that will make the example code work in the way the OP expected. Unlike the native Wordpress functions like `the_title`, it appears that the ACF `the_` functions don't return anything, they only output the value. To get it working using `the_field` would require using `echo` for the `<li>` and `</li>`.